# How do I integrate TFS Source Control with Business Intelligence Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, etl, business-intelligence

I am running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate -- which integrates with TFS source control.  However, when I run SQL Server 2008 Business Inteligence Studio, no source control is offered.  When I look under Tools... Options... Source Control... there are no plug-ins available.  Is this because BI Studio uses the 2008 Visual Studio Shell and I only have VS 2010?  TIA.

Answer (score 12):

I think you need to do the following:

1. Install Visual Studio Team Explorer 2008
2. Install Visual Studio 2008 SP1
3. Install Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Forward Compatibility Update for Team Foundation Server 2010 (KB974558)

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't work. Just won't connect. In that case repair/remove+reinstall SP1 and the SP1 Compatibility Update.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a list of items that you need to install to get TFS 2010 working in BIDS:
http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/04/ssis-2008-with-team-foundation-server.html

Answer (score 3):

One thing to keep in mind is when you connect to the server from BIS you need to use the full url http://tfsserver:8080/tfs.  If you don't use the full URL it will throw a connection error.

Comment: An additional note to this...not only did I have to use the full url (as you stated above), but I had to add my Team Project path onto the url as well (i.e. http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/TeamProject).

Comment: For completeness you need the **http** part as described in the answer _and_ the **team project** path, i.e. `http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/TeamProject`

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsgeneral/thread/ec58652c-04c4-47fb-ab4c-ac435ddfe019) you need VS 2005

Comment: I think that's if you want to connect VS2005 to TFS2008