# Connecting BIDS to TFS2010 problem - dialog doesn't allow a path to be specified

Tags: ssas, bids

I want to attach my BIDs (VS2008) to our Team Foundation Server 2010 to put the project artifacts under source control.
I've installed the Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Forward Compatibility Update for Team Foundation Server 2010 so I get the dialog to attach to the TFS server, but it only asks for the name of the server. When connecting via VS2010 I get the option to add the path as well as the server name which, evidently, is required to connect to our TFS server.

Is the URL/path saved to a solution or project file so I can hack it manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The secret is to type the full URL to the TFS project in the dialog box - it just seems to accept it without attempting to parse it.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Which version of VS2008 are you using? Also, at what point in your typing did the "Protocol" radio buttons get disabled?

Comment: BTW, I'm running "Version 9.0.21022.8" of "Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer" (from Help->About).

Comment: I followed the procedure detailed in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098532/, so I have SP1 installed for VS2008.